# Population moment condition versus sample moment condition

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Assume that the fourth moment of a random variable $X$ defined in $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P \right)$ satisfies:

> $$\mathbb{E} \left( X^4 \right) \leq C \left(\mathbb{E}(X^2) \right)^2, $$

for some constant $C$. For example, this is satisfied if $X\sim N(0,1)$ with $C=3$. Could I deduce from this that

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^4 \leq C \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right)^2,$$

for a random sample $\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n \right)$ with probabilty one for large $n$? It seems to me that this assertion follows from the strong law of large numbers but perhaps a more delicate treatment is required. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you need $\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$?  $\infty\leq C\infty^2$ isn't terribly useful, but is trivially true.

Comment: A remark that $C \ge 1 $ is *always* required, which can be shown directly: 
Let $X_i^2 = y_i \ge 0$ and you want 
$$
(\sum_{j=1}^n 1^2) (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2) \leq C \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \cdot 1 \right)^2,
$$
which, by the Cauchy-Schwartz-inequality, is - if at all - possible only for $C \ge1$, no matter what the distribution of the $X_i$. For $X\sim N(0,1)$ we have $C = 3$.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your remark.